# Filter based on a String comparison Function

Tags: javascript, filter

A am trying to filter the name property in each object (that is inside an array) based on whether the comparison function comes back true or not. However I am not sure if I am going about it correctly. I am using the localcomapre function. Below are my code snippets.

Below is my comparison hook.

```
export default function useLocalCompare(s1, s2) {
  s1.trim();
  s2.trim();

  if (s1.localeCompare(s2, undefined, { sensitivity: "base" }) === 0) {
    console.log("Both supplied parameters are the same");

    return "True";
  } else {
    return "False";
  }
}
```

And The filter function looks like

```
const filtteredarray = flatarrayofvalues.filter(
         useLocalCompare(placeholder.name, genre)
      );
```

Am I doing this directly. I only want it to filter out the object where the name property matches the genre value after both have gone through my **useLocalCompare** function.

Value of filtteredarray below

```
[{ id: 28, name: 'Action' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Adventure' },
  { id: 16, name: 'Animation' },
  { id: 35, name: 'Comedy' },
  { id: 80, name: 'Crime' },
  { id: 99, name: 'Documentary' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Drama' },
  { id: 10751, name: 'Family' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Fantasy' },
  { id: 36, name: 'History' },
  { id: 27, name: 'Horror' },
  { id: 10402, name: 'Music' },
  { id: 9648, name: 'Mystery' },
  { id: 10749, name: 'Romance' },
  { id: 878, name: 'Science Fiction' },
  { id: 10770, name: 'TV Movie' },
  { id: 53, name: 'Thriller' },
  { id: 10752, name: 'War' },
  { id: 37, name: 'Western' },
  { name: 'Trending' },
  { name: 'Top Rated' }
]
```

Comment: No that is not correct. The two boolean values in JavaScript are `true` and `false`, and they are not strings.  Also `.trim()` does not modify the original string; it returns a new string. So `s1.trim();` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can you show us the original array and what array/data structure you'd like after the filter

Comment: As mentioned, can you provide the `flatarrayofvalues` for reference? Where are the `placeholder.name` and `genre` values coming from? The `filter` method for arrays should have at least 1 parameter in the callback function so it can perform an evaluation on each element of the array.

Comment: @msmoore I have added the filtteredarray value.

Comment: The genre value comes from the URL. So it something like localhost/genre. I pull the genre down and then want to compare it to the name value of the array displayed above. @Sup3rkirby

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you are returning strings with "True" and "False", which are not boolean values and so they do not evaluate properly in the `filter()`.

Also, because your `useLocalCompare` function is just using an `if` statement evaluation, you can just return the `if` statement (as it evaluates to `true` or `false` itself).

So something like this should work:

```
export default function useLocalCompare(s1, s2) {
  // This evaluates to true or false, so we can return it
  return (s1.trim().localeCompare(s2.trim(), undefined, { sensitivity: "base" }) === 0);
}
```

It should also be noted that the `filter` method needs to use at least 1 parameter, being the current item from the array it is iterating through for evaluation. So your `filter` code needs to be slightly altered to use that parameter so it can actually loop through the `flattarrayofvalues` array and filter the results.

```
const filtteredarray = flatarrayofvalues.filter(placeholder =>
  useLocalCompare(placeholder.name, genre)
);
```

However, because this is just an `if` statement evaluation, you could just incorporate the whole thing into the `filter` directly.

```
const filtteredarray = flatarrayofvalues.filter(placeholder =>
  (placeholder.name.trim().localeCompare(genre.trim(), undefined, { sensitivity: "base" }) === 0)
);
```